# How to improve `extend` performance for custom Iterator

Tags: performance, rust, iterator

My app contains a custom RingBuffer implementation because I need
a few functions that are not provided by `VecDeque<u8>`.

A performance critical path for me is to `extend` a `Vec<u8>` with a subrange of this ringbuffer. So I benchmarked and found that the default `VecDeque` [`range`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.VecDeque.html#method.range) iter performs significantly better than mine, despite having literally the same datastructure.

[I checked in godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/rrcY59xWs) and as expected, the built-in one gets cool auto vectorization while my one doesn't.

While i will probably just end up writing manual `extend_from_slice` / `std::ptr::copy`'s for my usecase,
I was interested in finding out whether there was anything I could have done do to get comparable performance to the built-in Iterator. So far I tried using `&u8` for the iter but that was worse.

Is there some additional trait I could implement for my Iter or something?

My code looks something like this:

```rust
use std::collections::VecDeque;

pub struct RingbufIter<'a> {
    s1: std::slice::Iter<'a, u8>,
    s2: std::slice::Iter<'a, u8>,
}
impl<'a> Iterator for RingbufIter<'a> {
    type Item = u8;
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        match self.s1.next().copied() {
            Some(b) => Some(b),
            None => {
                // swap to reduce branches on subsequent `next` calls
                std::mem::swap(&mut self.s1, &mut self.s2);
                self.s1.next().copied()
            }
        }
    }
    fn size_hint(&self) -> (usize, Option<usize>) {
        let (s1_min, s1_max) = self.s1.size_hint();
        let (s2_min, s2_max) = self.s2.size_hint();
        (s1_min + s2_min, Some(s1_max.unwrap() + s2_max.unwrap()))
    }
}

#[no_mangle]
pub fn extend_from_custom_iter(src: RingbufIter, sink: &mut Vec<u8>)  {
    sink.extend(src)
}

#[no_mangle]
pub fn extend_from_vec_deque(src: &mut VecDeque<u8>, sink: &mut Vec<u8>)  {
    sink.extend(src.range(0..src.len()))
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Standard library uses a specialization to provide faster implementations of `Extend` for some collections it knows about. However you can't use it as it is unstable. <s>If you want to manually implement `Extend` you can do it for a *new type*</s>. Otherwise just write normal method `RingbufIter::extend_into_vec(&mut self, &mut Vec<u8>)`. For example:

```rust
#[no_mangle]
pub fn extend_from_custom_iter(src: RingbufIter, sink: &mut Vec<u8>)  {
    // Write optimized version that copies slices here
    // instead of relying on `Vec as Extend`.
}
```

This unfortunately will prevent you from writing generic code, but if your use case is to only use your custom ring buffer and `Vec`, this should be fine.

EDIT. Actually using new type and implementing `Extend` for it won't be possible, since `Extend::extend` is *generic* over iterator from which it extends. So to use specialized algorithm for your `RingbufIter` you would have to use another trait `SpecializedExtend` and implement it for `RingbufIter` and provide a blanked implementation for *all other* iterators, which is what std does internally and what is unstable. So you have to use concrete implementation method.

Comment: @ChrisB I've updated my answer since one of the solutions is impossible to do currently on stable rust.

Comment: @ChrisB "Unstable" means that some feature is still worked on, and can be only accessed on nightly (or in the internals of the standard library). It is locked behind a "feature gate" and can be often only partially implemented and be buggy. For what I know specialization is in very early stages of development, so I don't think you could successfully use it on nightly. You can check its current status in this [tracking issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/31844).

Comment: Thank you again! I was unaware of the specialization feature, which was why the code in std was quite confusing to read for me.